# How to name a file in the deepest level of a directory tree

Tags: bash

How do I name one random file in the deepest level of a directory tree using basic Bash commands and script?

I was searching for a way to do it as an one-liner and without functions. Assuming also that I'm starting in the current directory and then work towards the depth.

`find`, `grep`, `sed` and `awk` are acceptable commands.

My current attempt looks like this and does not work:

```
find -type d | declare COUNT=-1; declare P=""; while read LINE ; do echo $LINE; declare C; C=$(echo $LINE | cut -c3- | sed "s/\//\n\//g" | grep '/' -c); echo $C; if [ $COUNT -gt $C ]; then let COUNT=$C; let P=$LINE; echo "Done"; fi; done
```

*This would only find the directory.*

How could this be solved in the most simple way?

Comment: You call that a one-liner??

Comment: Do not cross-post. This is a duplicate of [How do I get this Bash-script to work?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27068/how-do-i-get-this-bash-script-to-work)

Comment: Why do so many people try to do so much on one line? I don't get it!

Comment: Why should they be one-liners? As you've seen , when a one-liner goes wrong, it's very hard to debug! Open an editor and write a bash script!

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times.

Comment: Also see [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's an odd request!

I'd use `find` + `awk` to grab a file in the deepest directory:

```
bash-3.2$ deepest=$(find / -type f | awk -F'/' 'NF > depth {
>     depth = NF;
>     deepest = $0;
> }
>
> END {
>     print deepest;
> }')
```

Using `${deepest}` in your `mv` command is left as an exercise but the following five lines may help you further:

```
bash-3.2$ echo "${deepest}"
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/vendor/tzinfo-0.3.12/tzinfo/definitions/America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires.rb

bash-3.2$ echo "${deepest%.*}"
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/vendor/tzinfo-0.3.12/tzinfo/definitions/America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires

bash-3.2$ echo "${deepest%/*}"
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/vendor/tzinfo-0.3.12/tzinfo/definitions/America/Argentina

bash-3.2$ echo "${deepest##*/}"
Buenos_Aires.rb

bash-3.2$ echo "${deepest##*.}"
rb
```

---

### Following update to question:

> `find -type d` [...] "*This would only find the directory.* [...] How could this be solved in the most simple way?".

By supplying `-type f` to [`find`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/find/) to find all *files* (`f`), not all *directories* (`d`).

Comment: I've updated my question and added the command-line script I wrote to attempt to do this. It's not working. Some feedback from others will be welcomed.

Comment: Your one-liner is incomprehensible to me. I'm sorry I cannot debug that for you.
Does my example not do what you asked for?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, it does. I was just seeking for different ways of tackling the problem as I'm quite new to Bash and the paradigm. Your solution does it!!

Comment: I see. There are many ways to solve this. I recommend my own solution since it involves only one `|`, keeping subprocesses to a minimum.

Comment: N.B: If you just want to print the filename, you can omit `deepest=$( [...] )` and start from `find`. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing some curly-bracketing, you inverted the comparison, and you need to print the result:

```
find -type d | {
  declare COUNT=-1
  declare P=""
  while read LINE
    do echo $LINE
    declare C=$(echo $LINE | cut -c3- | sed "s/\//\n\//g" | grep '/' -c)
    echo $C
    if [ $C -gt $COUNT ]; then let COUNT=$C; let P=$LINE; echo "Done"; fi
  done
  echo deepest: "$P"
}
```

Slightly improved version, with debugging stuff thrown away:

```
find -type d -links 2 | (
  declare COUNT=-1
  P=""
  while IFS= read -r LINE; do
    declare C=$(echo $LINE | tr -cd / | wc -c)
    if [ $C -gt $COUNT ]; then let COUNT=$C; P=$LINE; fi
  done
  echo deepest: "$P"
)
```

Comment: @Stéphane, could you specify the shell you used? The question is tagged `bash`, but I suppose you used something else, as bash` gives this: “bash: local: can only be used in a function”.

Comment: @manatwork: Indeed I forgot to test again with `bash`. I used `zsh` and it was accepted. The best is maybe to use a subshell to deal with those little scope issues.

Comment: A faster way to obtain the value of `C` is `C=${LINE//[^\/]/}; C=${#C}`. Also, you don't need the `declare` keyword if you're using a subshell to make variables local.

Comment: Clever trick. Oh, and I think the point of declare was to make those variables integer variables, so I did not changed it.

Answer (score 3):

```
find -type f | awk -F/ 'NF > maxdepth { maxdepth = NF; file = $0 }; END {print file}'
```

And it seems this is essentially the same as [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27022/11750) on the other question you posted, what's wrong with that/this one?

Answer (score 2):

With zsh:

```
f=(**/*(D.Oe:'REPLY=${REPLY//[^\/]}':[1])) && mv -- $f $f:h/new-name
```

We use `zsh` recursive globbing (`**/*`) and glob qualifiers `(...)`, with `D` to include dot-files, `.` to only select regular files and `Oe:'code'` to define a sort order (here reversed because of the upper case `O`) based on the value of `$REPLY` after execution of the `code`.

In that `code`, the current file is passed as `$REPLY`. We remove everything but `/` characters in that `$REPLY`, and that's what is used for the sort order. So the file with the most `/` sorts last, first once reversed and we select that first one with `[1]`.

The `bash` with (recent) GNU tools equivalent could be something like:

```
(
  export LC_ALL=C
  find . -type f -print0 |
    sed -z 'h;s:[^/]::g;G;s:[^/]::' |
    sort -rz |
    sed -z 's:/*::;q' |
    tr '\0' '\n'
)
```

Comment: I don't know `zsh` particularly, but I'm betting this is the *only* one of the many answers given so far that actually correctly handles any and all special characters in filenames, including newlines.  (You should mention that in the answer if so; this deserves more attention.)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with these, although they will fail on file names containing leading spaces. The first outputs just the file name, the second includes the path to that file too:

```
find -type f | sed 's:[^/]*/: :g' | LC_ALL=C sort | head -1 | sed 's/^ *//'

find -type f | sed 'h;s:[^/]*/: :g;G;s/\n/\t/' | LC_ALL=C sort | head -1 | sed 's/.*\t//'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function step () {
    d=$1
    d=$((d+1))
    res=$(find -mindepth $d -type d ! -empty)
    test -n "$res" && step $d || echo $((d-1))
}

find -mindepth $(step 0) -type d ! -empty | head -n 1
```

Recursively step deeper and deeper into directories, as long as they contain a file (`! -empty`). From the last step, we have to subtract 1, and we can then use the result in a second `find` command.

Answer (score 0):

The following script prints out the longest paths in the file system and/or below the current directory, but instead of using `find`, it takes advantage of the existing `locate` database of (potentially very long) paths without searching/traversing (potentially very deep) directory structures. Note it does count *directories* to determine depth, not just the length of the path (but it could easily be modified/simplified to do either).

```
$ cat find-longest-path.sh
#!/bin/bash
pattern=$1
locate -r "^${PWD}/${pattern}" \
   | while read f; do printf "$(tr -cd / <<< "$f" | wc -c):$f\n"; done \
   | sort -nr -t: -k1 \
   | head -5
```

This prints out the deepest 5 paths (`head -5`) of a file name pattern (regexp) starting from `pwd`. Output is prefixed by the depth (i.e., number of `/`'s in the path). To search for just a specific filename and/or pattern, anywhere in the file system, remove `$PWD` and just search for `locate -r /some_file$` (...etc, etc).

For example,

```
$ ./find-longest-path.sh 'foo.*log$'
5:/path/to/deep/path/foo-12345.log
3:/path/to/shallow/foobar.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised no one mentioned using `%d`.

You can list all nested subfolders, and sort them by depth, using:

```
find . -type d -printf '%d:%p\n' | sort -t: -k1 -g -r > /tmp/foo.txt
```

where

- `.` can be replaced with the root folder;
- `-type d` finds nested subfolders (replace with `-type f` for files instead);
- `%d:%p` prints the depth, followed by the path;
- `-t:` means the separator is `:`;
- `-k1` means we want to sort by the first key/column;
- `-g` means that we want to sort numbers;
- `-r` means that we want the deepest folders to show first.

The result of this command are streamed into file `/tmp/foo.txt` (replace as desired, you can also use `mktemp` if needed).

The deepest level can then be determined automatically with:

```
D=$(head -n 1 /tmp/foo.txt | awk -F ":" '{print $1}')
```

If you want to filter only those folders or files at depth `D`, you can use:

```
awk -F ":" '{ if ($1 == D) print $2 }' /tmp/foo.txt
```

Finally, to select a line randomly amongst the results, pipe with `| shuf -n 1`.

---

Putting this into a script `random_deep_file <Folder> <Depth>`:

```
Folder=$1

# Sort files by depth into temporary file
Temp=$(mktemp)
find "$Folder" -type f -printf '%d:%p\n' | sort -t: -k1 -g -r >| "$Temp"

# Determine deepest level if not specified
[ $# -lt 2 ] && { D=$(head -n 1 "$Temp" | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'); } || D=$2

# Select a random file at that depth
awk -F ":" "{ if (\$1 == $D) print \$2 }" "$Temp" | shuf -n 1
```

> Note:
>   If you are on OSX, you need to install (with Homebrew) and use `gfind` and `gshuf` instead.